# Retrieving user information with Google sign in

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

I used google auth. for my app. I need to retrieve info of the signed-in user. Especially photo. But when I try to use that code block the **getActivity()** gives error says *"none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"* how can I use that. Also answers are can be in java.

Comment: try `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity().context);`

Comment: @VictorS getActivity()

Comment: @AnimeshSahu doesnt work

Comment: getLastSignedInAccount checks if the user has already signed in. Could you try GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)

Comment: @BeratcanGüreş could you show us what is getActivity returning value, or its definition?

Comment: @VictorS it worked after i wrote "(this)" thank you for the answer

Comment: @BeratcanGüreş your welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sign In account [getLastSignedInAccount](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#check_for_an_existing_signed-in_user) checks if the user is already signed in. The current class object **this** is passed as an argument to the method call.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```